apache beam WirteToBigQuery write optimisation
I have a streaming pipeline where I'm apllying a window of 30s and grouping in ("customerId" + "siteId", element) tuple.
How can I apply a dynamic table name based on the companyId+siteId, something around this lines?:
f'{GCP_PROJECT}.{customerId}.{siteId}'
Is there a way to take the first tuple which has the two variables needed to specify the table name? How can this be done in an efficient way?
bq_results = (
            pipeline_bq
            | 'Add Timestamp' >> beam.Map(lambda elem: beam.window.TimestampedValue(elem, int(elem['measurement_time'])))
            | 'Window into window_size Seconds' >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(window_size), allowed_lateness=beam.window.Duration(seconds=30))
            | 'creating tupple' >> beam.Map(lambda element: (element.get("companyId", ""), element.get("siteId", ""), element))
            | 'Eliminating the key value pair' >> beam.Map(lambda kv_pair: [element for element in kv_pair[1]])
            | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                table_fn,
                schema=schema,
                method="STREAMING_INSERTS",


Check this example: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataflow-cookbook/blob/main/Python/bigquery/write_bigquery_dynamic.py

Thanks for pointing that out XQ Hu. I'm doing a similar approach, but what makes a difference is the activation of:

triggering_frequency=60,
with_auto_sharding=True

With these options I'm seeing a batch size of around 16 rows for 60m window. I will do some more tests and update this post with the findings

I'm getting the following error (once every 2-5m) with a window of 120s (2m):
BigQuery/_StreamToBigQuery/StreamInsertRows/ParDo(BigQueryWriteFn)-ptransform-59, state=process-msecs} for at least 26399.08 seconds without outputting or completing.

using the following WritoToBigQuery approach:
| 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                table=lambda element: f'{GCP_PROJECT}:test_dataset.{element.get("siteId")}',
                schema=schema,
                method="STREAMING_INSERTS",
                triggering_frequency=120,
                with_auto_sharding=True,
                batch_size=200,

Any suggestion to improve the performance of WriteToBigQuery?

Was the BQ table created with a schema?
